# Veikk 1560 (Wacom Cintiq alternative) compatibility issues

Tags: modeling, sculpting, error, compatibility

Hello dear Blender users!

I'm an avid Blender user myself, and I've been looking for an option to sculpt faster than with my mouse (LOL, to be fair, I'm pretty decent at it anyway but it's veeeeryyyy slooooow). I hate regular tablets so I've saved up for a tactile-monitor-based tablet such as the Wacom Cintiqs, although a cheaper one as I believe Wacoms are overpriced AF.

I settled with the Veikk 1560 ( [https://www.amazon.com/VEIKK-Drawing-Graphics-Shortcut-ScrollDial/dp/B07DJ9NGNV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07DJ9NGNV) ) which at the moment seems to be a brilliant alternative for such a "cheap" price of 350$-ish (although there is no screen touching unless you're using the Pen, so... not a capacitive screen if that's what you're looking for).

I've been using it the whole afternoon and tried it up in both Blender and Photoshop (plus Google Chrome, to check for compatibility issues since Blender is **NOT recognizing the hotkeys I'm assigning through the Veikk drivers**, more on this later).

**Pressure sensitivity seems to be ok**, it's working perfectly. Even **certain hotkey associations** (done through the Veikk drivers) **are being recognized** directly **in Blender**: as an example, if I associate right or left click to the pen buttons everything seems to work as expected.

I do however want both buttons on the pen to work as ALT and SHIFT keys or as a Middle Mouse so that I can sculpt and move the camera around with ease (I use Maya navigation). For some reason, NONE of these seem to work at all.

As a curious fact, the first button I ever configured on the pen was ALT, and it worked fine for a few minutes until I did some more changes on the driver and suddenly it stopped recognizing any of these.

Any ideas as to what might be wrong or how to fix it? I am 100% sure it should be doable; as I said before, not only certain hotkeys are being detected, but I was actually able to use the 2nd button on the pen as ALT key for a few minutes before it all broke for some weird reason.

**As a side note**, this is why **I've checked the monitor with Chrome too (to make sure the hotkeys actually were being detected by the PC)**, and as a matter of fact **they are being recognized** (SHIFT on Pen acts as a shift when writing stuff down and so on).

**It really seems as if Blender was somehow overriding the hotkey configurations** that I am assigning through the Veikk driver, both on the Pen and Tablet buttons (which are 100% unsynced from the functions I am assigning to them through the driver).

Any info would be greatly appreciated as it would turn this tablet into a very cheap alternative for a Cintiq monitor and I am sure many will find this VERY appealing.

Thank you and I'm glad I joined this forum! It's about time I start asking questions instead of spending wasted countless hours figuring stuff out by myself LOL.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**UPDATE 1:** Ok... so I'm a **leftie** so I **turned my monitor upside down** and vertically flipped it through the screen options on Windows (from the beginning). I hadn't thought about it, but **naturally my tablet-monitor commands were flipped too so that's why they were not reacting as desired**. Once accounting for this I realized that the **Tablet button hotkeys** that I associate through the Veikk drivers **DO in fact work** (**to a 90% extent**, for some reason Blender takes my CTRL+z command and CTRL+SHIFT+z command as the same, so basically I can only undo (with both buttons)).

As for the Penn, the commands are (**MOSTLY, again**) ALSO working! **However** there just seems to be NO WAY for me to simply associate alt and shift to these buttons and use them as desired (to pan and rotate the view).

Perhaps this will cue you in as to what the problem is, since at this point I am almost 90% sure whatever is left to be configured should be configured on the Blender side (I seriously doubt this is an issue with the Veikk 1560, as everything seems to be working fine on that side).

Comment: non-wacom tablet have more driver compatibility issues. Because they have less time to improve the driver software. wacom has the longest history.

Answer (score 2):

you can contact their tech support , this may the issue of veikk 1560 driver . so you can't use the two buttons of the stylus .

I've had a [XP-Pen G430 OSU tablet](https://www.xp-pen.com/goods/show/id/36.html) for many years that has proved to be handy. And I've seen a top-of-the-line XP-Pen pen display monitor that cost about 450 dollars. This 16-inch Artist 15.6 Pro drawing tablet with screen intended for people who want a pen monitor product but find the high-end prices too high for them. That is, people like me.

For people like me, this is impressive. Being able to use the pen right on the screen makes a big difference. And make no mistake, the pen draws right where it contacts the screen. There are no problems with parallax (at least that I could see -- I didn't perform any tests). That makes sketching and drawing almost like using a pen on paper. Better in some ways. it works well with Blender and Photoshop art programs .